# Meteor change from local to remote DB

Tags: mongodb, meteor, webstorm, mlab

I'm trying to connect my development app to a remote mongodb at mongolabs. I have tried to change the environment settings in the `settings.json` file to:

```
"env": {
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxxx@xxxx.mongolab.com:xxxx/xxxx"
}
```

and to:

```
"env": {
    "export MONGO_URL": "mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxxx@xxxx.mongolab.com:xxxx/xxxx"
}
```

I have also tried these two above commands in the terminal, which gives me a error of `'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Or:

```
'MONGO_URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

Where else can the `environment` variables be changed to connect to the remote DB?

Answer (score 6):

From the command line run this:

Linux:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxxx@xxxx.mongolab.com:xxxx/xxxx
```

Windows:

```
set MONGO_URL=mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxxx@xxxx.mongolab.com:xxxx/xxxx
```

I don't think "env" in the settings.json file is supported.

EDIT:

If you want to control this based on logged in user (i.e. if you have a dev user, prod user, etc.) then add this export line (linux only) to your .bashrc file so that when the user logs in, this environment variable is automatically set.

Comment: Thanks.....If I want to add this to a bash file, where would I add the file in the meteor project? I'm using Windows7 and the Webstorm IDE

Comment: Also when I run this in the command line I get the error `export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: You can go into your system environment variables and set it there on a per user basis I believe. If you are on windows, run this command: set MONGO_URL=mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxxx@xxxx.mongolab.com:xxxx/xxxx

Comment: Thanks  but tried to run this from the terminal  with `set `and it still saves to the local mongoDB not remote instance.

Comment: Did you restart the meteor instance? It will require a restart of meteor. Check your environment variables to ensure that MONGO_URL is set by running this command: "set". If it is present then the only other idea I have is that meteor is being run as a different user or in a different environment, and can't see that variable. You can try adding the environment variable to the meteor startup command to ensure it is being read: "MONGO_URL="mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxxx@xxxx.mongolab.com:xxxx/xxxx" meteor"

Comment: I added the `env variable` to the startup function like this: `if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Meteor.startup(function(){
        process.env.MONGO_URL = "mongodb://xxxxx:xxxx@xxxx.mongolab.com:xxxx/xx";
        console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL); // prints correct MONGO_URL
    })` This prints out that the variable points to remote MongoLab DB but everything is still saved in the local DB. I've restarted the appliction also.

Comment: Can you try doing this via "set" on the command line rather than within the application? The connection to the mongo instance may have been already been created, and setting it after it's started up may not work.

Comment: Although that sets the `MONGO_URL ` to the mongolabs db in the command line everything is still saved in the local DB